Nuget NU3034 from package Azure.Identity
Building dotnet core 8.0.204 on WSL2 (Ubuntu on Windows).
We recently upgraded to using version 1.11.0 of package Azure.Identity (and a bunch of others) and I'm getting this very persistent error:
$ dotnet restore
  Package 'Azure.Identity 1.11.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Subject Name: CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
  Package 'Azure.Identity 1.11.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA256 hash: 566A31882BE208BE4422F7CFD66ED09F5D4524A5994F50CCC8B05EC0528C1353
  Package 'Azure.Identity 1.11.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Valid from: 07/27/2023 01:00:00 to 10/18/2026 00:59:59
/home/richard/myproj/myproj.csproj : error NU3034: Package 'Azure.Identity 1.11.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package was not repository signed with a certificate listed by this repository.

However I've got the fingerprint registered:
$ dotnet nuget trust list
Registered trusted signers:

 1.   Microsoft [author]
      Certificate fingerprint(s):
        SHA256 - 566A31882BE208BE4422F7CFD66ED09F5D4524A5994F50CCC8B05EC0528C1353

My basic NuGet.Config (in the folder of the project) is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>

  <trustedSigners>
    <author name="Microsoft">
      <certificate fingerprint="3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
      <certificate fingerprint="AA12DA22A49BCE7D5C1AE64CC1F3D892F150DA76140F210ABD2CBFFCA2C18A27" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
      <certificate fingerprint="566A31882BE208BE4422F7CFD66ED09F5D4524A5994F50CCC8B05EC0528C1353" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
    </author>
  </trustedSigners>

  <config>
    <add key="signatureValidationMode" value="accept" />
  </config>
</configuration>

...although I've had lots of variations and put the same into ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config too.
I've tried all sorts of things including nuget config -set signatureValidationMode=accept and scouring the system for other NuGet.Config files.
If I revert to an earlier version of the package I don't get this error but get a known vulnerability error, so not sure if the previous version isn't signed or if the vulnerability error is shown in preference to the signing error.
I've been through all articles on here and others on google - most about NU3034 are about a different wording of error - "not by a trusted signer" rather than "not repository signed with a certificate listed by this repository".

A colleague (via ChatGPT!) told me to run this which fixed the issue:
dotnet nuget locals all --clear


This didn't seem to work for me. I get the error only in test projects that reference a project which in turn references the Azure.Identity package. If I add the package as a top level reference to those test projects it goes away. I'm using central package management and transitive pinning which may be a factor. All projects are subject to the same (updated) nuget.config.
I will continue to investigate.
